# Приостановить работу приложения до прихода широковещательного сообщения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, асинхронность

Существует приложение, осуществляющее сканирование сетей WiFi по нажатию кнопки и затем выводящее на экран результаты. Результаты сканирования приходят в широковещательном сообщении от ОС, и в методе OnReceive приемника копируются в список, который возвращается вызывающей процедуре. Код приемника:

```
BroadcastReceiver wifi_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("WifScanner", "onReceive");
        List<ScanResult> temp = wifi.getScanResults();

        for (ScanResult i : temp)
        {
            results.add(i);
        }

        context.unregisterReceiver(this);
    }
};
```

Непосредственно вызываемый метод:

```
public ArrayList<ScanResult> scanNetworks()
{
    context.registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    wifi.startScan();

    Log.d("WifScanner", "scanWifiNetworks");

    return results;
}
```

Код, вызывающий метод:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    results = scanner.scanNetworks();
    Log.d("Scanned:", String.valueOf(results.size()));
    for (ScanResult res : results)
    {
        Log.d("network:","SSID: [" + res.SSID + "]" + " Capabilities: [" + res.capabilities + "]");
    }
}
```

Так как результаты сканирования приходят не сразу, при нажатии на кнопку метод сканирования может вернуть пустой список результатов, из-за чего в свою очередь на экране ничего не отобразится и для получения желаемого результата необходимо нажимать на кнопку неопределенное количество раз, пока во внутренний контейнер класса сканирования не будут записаны результаты методом OnReceive. Мне необходимо приостановить выполнение программы до того момента, пока это не произойдет. Можно было бы сделать sleep секунд на 5, но это не особо корректно, хотелось бы более детерминированный метод. Гугление не помогло.

Comment: я не знаю как будет с анрюхой но в кор джава можно через шедулеры

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку (scan networks) сделать кнопку неактивной и активировать ее только после прихода бродкаста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких асинхронных задач обычно пробрасывают колбеки.

1. Удалить переменную `results`.
2. Создайте интерфейс.

   ```
   public interface OnBroadcastReceiverResult {
       public void onResult( List<ScanResult> results);
   }
   ```
3. Унаследуйтесь от `BroadcastReceiver` и свой конструктор сделайте:

   ```
   public abstract class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       private OnBroadcastReceiverResult _callback;

       public MyBroadcastReceiver(OnBroadcastReceiverResult callBack) {
           super();

           _callback = callBack;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Первоначально пусть `wifi_receiver` будет равен `null`:

   ```
   BroadcastReceiver wifi_receiver = null;
   ```
5. Переделайте `scanNetworks` так:

   ```
   public void scanNetworks(final OnBroadcastReceiverResult callBack) {
       if(wifi_receiver == null){
           wifi_receiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(callBack)
           {
               @Override
               public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent)
               {
                   Log.d("WifScanner", "onReceive");
                   List<ScanResult> temp = wifi.getScanResults();

                   callBack.onResult(temp);

                   context.unregisterReceiver(this);
               }
           };
       }

       context.registerReceiver(wifi_receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
       wifi.startScan();

       Log.d("WifScanner", "scanWifiNetworks");
   }
   ```
6. А `onClick` так:

   ```
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
       scanner.scanNetworks(new OnBroadcastReceiverResult() {
           @Override public void onResult(List<ScanResult> results) {
               Log.d("Scanned:", String.valueOf(results.size()));
               for (ScanResult res : results)
               {
                   Log.d("network:","SSID: [" + res.SSID + "]" + " Capabilities: [" + res.capabilities + "]");
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   Теперь в `onResult` у вас будут приходить сети по факту их получения.

P.S. пишу на коленке без редактора. Но, думаю, мысль поймёте основную.